# Android Run time Error Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now

Tags: java, android, realm, apk

Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.

realm-android-0.86.0.jar (io.realm:realm-android:0.86.0)

- Alternatively, set `android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true` to continue with previous behavior.
- Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the
  future. See [this](https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html) for more details.

Comment: please show the contents of your build.gradle( module:app) file

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.greefitech.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

Comment: https://ibb.co/mL1f59   @SantiagoCeladaGonzalez

Comment: These code is crud opreation using realm .I copy these code in this URL (http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/realm-mobile-database-implementation-in-android).It run seperately but it not run my project.what are dependency add.

Comment: See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6090#issuecomment-409608382 it might help

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Comment: Thank Very much Bro

Comment: Bro another error in prodect this line->                myRealm = Realm.getInstance(customer.this);

Comment: that's because `Realm.getInstance(Context)` was replaced with `Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration)` in about.. Realm 0.83.0, actually, and all deprecated methods were removed in 0.91.0

Answer (score 0):

Realm-Java 0.86.0 is 3 years old.

The latest version of Realm-Java is 5.4.1.

If this is a new project, just use Realm-Java 5.4.1 instead, as per [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.4.1"
    }
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

---

If this is an old project, refer to [this answer](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6090#issuecomment-409608382). Realm 0.87.5 and before does not have the Realm-Transformer yet, so that can be omitted.

Comment: after I add shown error MainActivity cannot be converted to RealmConfiguration

Comment: myRealm = Realm.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

Comment: That's because Realm.getInstance(Context) was replaced with Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration) in Realm 0.83.0